# Can I replace polyester capacitor by ceramic in audio circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor

I'm redesigning an amplifier circuit. I'm using the `TEA2025B`. In the circuit there are some polyester capacitors, I would like to know if there are problems in replacing these polyester capacitors with ceramic capacitors. I have found ceramic capacitors with capacitance and voltage equal to the capacitors of polyester, but I do not know if it is correct to change.

Comment: Microphony comes to mind.

Comment: Depending on the dielectric, ceramic caps tend to be less precise, and have capacitances that vary with voltage.  By the time you've gotten a really good ceramic cap it's a C0G, and the last time I looked those were bigger and more expensive than polyester caps at typical audio ratings.

Comment: Better you should replace them with polypropylene.

Comment: In short: it'll probably work, but there might be weird side effects. Better to stick with film caps.

Comment: I side with Robert. Polypropylene capacitors can have a high cost, but they are the only capacitors that can tolerate high current high frequency square waves without shorting or oxidizing. I have tested many types so I know this to be true, if pulse is no more than 2/3 rated AC+DC peak volts.

Comment: Various capacitors have more or less residual charge, depending on dielectric and rigidity of the plate/dielectric bonds. Do not go cheap on the capacitors. If interested, to to diyAudio.com and read various discussions on this.